# Fragment and Text to speech and slide menu

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, text-to-speech, slidingmenu

I want to know how can I shut down TTS while I'm using Fragment.

I'm getting these errors when I try to go back to previous fragment:

```
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095): Activity com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@b1322460 that was originally bound here
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@b1322460 that was originally bound here
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:974)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:868)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1452)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1440)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:496)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:685)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:655)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:608)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:582)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:567)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP.CustomListViewAddapter.getView(CustomListViewAddapter.java:113)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095): Activity com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@b131d010 that was originally bound here
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection@b131d010 that was originally bound here
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:974)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:868)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1452)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1440)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:496)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:685)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:655)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:608)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:582)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:567)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.PishgamanIt.ETPUP.CustomListViewAddapter.getView(CustomListViewAddapter.java:113)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:890)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-07 00:25:20.972: E/ActivityThread(2095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I tried to put this in all fragment and activity

```java
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView(); 
    CustomListViewAddapter.tts.shutdown();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView(); 
    CustomListViewAddapter.tts.shutdown();
}
```

But I am still getting those errors whenever I try to go back to the main page using < in top slide menu.

Comment: It seems that you're initializing a new `TextToSpeech` instance from each call to the `getView()` method of your adapter, and only holding a reference to the last one (which is the one that is shut down).

Comment: First, thank you for your reply. Second, you are right, I have tts in my customlistViewAddapter which defined like this

public class CustomListViewAddapter extends ArrayAdapter<getAllData> implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
........
tts = new TextToSpeech(context, CustomListViewAddapter.this);
if (tts != null) {
     String text =list.getEnglish().toString();
     if (text != null) {
      if (!tts.isSpeaking()) {
       speakOut(text);
      }
     }
    }
..........
}

but, I don't know how to shut it down in that class.  Do you have any idea? thank you again.

Comment: Don't create a new instance of `TextToSpeech` from the `getView()` method. Initialize one instance of it at initialization time (inside the constructor).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't undrestand what you mean?
this is my constractor. public CustomListViewAddapter(Context context, int resource, List<getAllData> items) {
     super(context, resource);
 }. what should I do?

Comment: Initialize your `tts` variable from there, and remove the initialization in `getView()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70499/discussion-between-corsair992-and-m-r-sh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks to @corsai992.

Second, I added tts to my CustomListViewAddapter contractor and from whenever I need that CustomListViewAddapter I created tts and pass it to that class.

happy codding :)